# how to add page option to my wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I designed a WordPress template

Then I added the settings like logo and color change

Now I want to add the settings for the front page, settings like the image below

In the picture, there are 8 Div(class or Items in the **content**)

[image]

How can I enable or disable any of the 8 items (div or class) using the settings? (for display on the front page(index))?

I have a lot of interest in the design of WordPress

please guide me

Thanks

Comment: you can add a checkbox to enable or disable option?

Comment: yes
but I cant code it :(

Comment: please post your code here what you have tried